# jQuery Tabbed Cont

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So why isn't my .active class being placed onto the second .purchase-content class? The .purchase__tabs element works just fine, just the nth-child part of my JS I'm having problems with.

JS

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".purchase-tab").click(function(e){
          if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
              var tabNum = $(this).index();
              var nthChild = tabNum+1;
              $(".purchase-tab.active").removeClass("active");
              $(this).addClass("active");
              $(".purchase-content.active").removeClass("active");
              $(".purchase-content:nth-child("+nthChild+")").addClass("active");
          }
      });
  });
```

CSS

```
.purchase-content {
  display: none;
}

.purchase-content.active  {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="purchase__tabs">
      <div class="col-50 purchase-tab active">
        <h2>Upfront Payment</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-50 purchase-tab">
        <h2>Pay Monthly</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
```

With great offers on bot CapEx and OpEx purchasing you can choose a
              payment option that works best for you. Help maximise your cash flow with
              HP’s monthly subscription. You even get to renew your technology every
              three years.

### HP Slice

## £799

#### special price RRP: £974

Buy HP Slice

### Z2 Mini

## £735

#### special price RRP: £768

Buy Z2 Mini

### Elite x360

## £1399

#### special price RRP: £1636

Buy Elite x360

```
    <div class="purchase-content">
      <p>With great offers on both CapEx and OpEx purchasing you can choose a
      payment option that works best for you. Help maximise your cash flow
      with HPs monthly subscription, you even get to renew your technology
      every three years</p>
      <div class="col-third">
        <h2>HP Slice</h2>
        <h1>£23</h1>
        <h3>per month over 18 months</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn--yellow">Buy HP Slice</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-third">
        <h2>Z2 Mini</h2>
        <h1>£42</h1>
        <h3>per month over 18 months</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn--yellow">Buy Z2 Mini</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-third">
        <h2>Elite x360</h2>
        <h1>£89</h1>
        <h3>per month over 18 months</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn--yellow">Buy HP Slice</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I can't figure out your problem. This is just working...? When I click on the seond tab the second content gets visible and the active class will be set?
Can you explain your issue again a little bit more clear? And you are talking about the second content. In your example is only one present?

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".purchase-tab").click(function(e){
          if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
              var tabNum = $(this).index();
              var nthChild = tabNum+1;
              $(".purchase-tab.active").removeClass("active");
              $(this).addClass("active");
              $(".purchase-content.active").removeClass("active");
              $(".purchase-content:nth-child("+nthChild+")").addClass("active");
          }
      });
  });
```

```css
.purchase-content {
  display: none;
}

.purchase-content.active  {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
}

.purchase-tab.active {
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="purchase__tabs">
  <div class="col-50 purchase-tab active">
    <h2>Upfront Payment</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-50 purchase-tab">
    <h2>Pay Monthly</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="purchase-content active">
    test
  </div>

  <div class="purchase-content">
    Content 2 
  </div>
</div>
```